# Bootstrap TagsInput with EntityType dropdown values (Symfony)

Tags: forms, doctrine-orm, symfony4, bootstrap-tags-input

I'm making a form to register books (Symfony 4), each with a unique publisher (ManyToOne) and one or many authors (ManyToMany). Both fields are filled in the form as tags, with **Bootstrap TagsInput**, so that if the user types in those fields, they will suggest the list of values in the DB tables, and if not, the new values will be inserted when submitting, along with the other book data.

I followed the official example of Best Practices on the Symfony website, and the tagging system **works for authors**, because it's a CollectionType, but **not with the publisher**, because it's an EntityType. How could I adapt it? Fails to transform publisher values into comma-separated strings so it can be recognized by TagsInput.

## Book Entity (App\Entity\Book.php)

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

class Book
{
    /**
    * @var \Publisher
    *
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Publisher", cascade={"persist"})
    * @ORM\JoinColumns({
    *   @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false, name="publisher_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    * })
    */
    private $publisher;

    /**
     * @var Author[]|ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Author", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="authors_books")
     */
    private $authors;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->authors = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getPublisher()
    {
        return $this->publisher;
    }

    public function getAuthors(): Collection
    {
        return $this->authors;
    }
}
```

## Book Form (App\Form\BookType.php)

```
namespace App\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

use App\Form\Type\PublisherType;
use App\Form\Type\AuthorType;

class BookType extends AbstractType {   
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options){
        $builder
        ->add('publisher', PublisherType::class, array(
            'label' => 'Publisher',
        ))
        ->add('authors', AuthorType::class, array(
            'label' => 'Author/s'
        ))
    }
}
```

## AuthorType

```
namespace App\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\DataTransformer\CollectionToArrayTransformer;
use App\Form\DataTransformer\AuthorToStringTransformer;
use App\Repository\AuthorRepository;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormView;

class AuthorType extends AbstractType { 
    private $authors;

    public function __construct(AuthorRepository $authors_repo)
    {
       $this->authors = $authors_repo;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options){
       $builder
            ->addModelTransformer(new CollectionToArrayTransformer(), true)
            ->addModelTransformer(new AuthorToStringTransformer($this->authors), true)
        ;
    }

    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options): void
    {
        $view->vars['authors'] = $this->authors->findAll();
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return TextType::class;
    }
}
```

## PublisherType

```
namespace App\Form\Type;

use App\Form\DataTransformer\EntityToArrayTransformer;
use App\Form\DataTransformer\PublisherToStringTransformer;
use App\Repository\PublisherRepository;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormView;

class PublisherType extends AbstractType {

    private $publishers;

    public function __construct(PublisherRepository $publisher_repo) {
        $this->publishers = $publisher_repo;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder
        ->addModelTransformer(new EntityToArrayTransformer(), true)
        ->addModelTransformer(new PublisherToStringTransformer($this->publishers), true);
    }

    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options): void
    {
        $publishers = $this->publishers->findAll();
    }

    public function getParent() 
    {
        return TextType::class;
    }
}
```

## CollectionToArrayTransformer

```
namespace Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\DataTransformer;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Symfony\Component\Form\DataTransformerInterface;

class CollectionToArrayTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{
    public function transform($collection)
    {
        if (null === $collection) {
            return [];
        }
        if (\is_array($collection)) {
            return $collection;
        }
        return $collection->toArray();
    }
}
```

## EnityToArrayTransformer

```
namespace App\Form\DataTransformer;

use Symfony\Component\Form\DataTransformerInterface;

class EntityToArrayTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{
    public function transform($entity)
    {
        if (null === $entity) {
            return [];
        }
        return [$entity];
    }
}
```

## AuthorToStringTransformer

```
namespace App\Form\DataTransformer;

use App\Entity\Author;
use App\Repository\AuthorRepository;
use Symfony\Component\Form\DataTransformerInterface;

class AuthorToStringTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{
    private $authors;

    public function __construct(AuthorRepository $authors)
    {
        $this->authors = $authors;
    }

    public function transform($authors): string
    {
        /* @var Author[] $authors */
        return implode(',', $authors);
    }

    public function reverseTransform($string): array
    {
    ...
    }
}
```

## PublisherToStringTransformer

```
namespace App\Form\DataTransformer;

use App\Entity\Publisher;
use App\Repository\PublisherRepository;
use Symfony\Component\Form\DataTransformerInterface;

class PublisherToStringTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface 
{
    private $publishers;

    public function __construct(PublisherRepository $publishers)
    {
       $this->publishers = $publishers;
    }

    public function transform($publisher): string
    {
        /* @var Publisher[] $publisher */
        return implode(',', $publisher);
    }

    public function reverseTransform($publisher): string
    {
    ...
   }
}
```

## Form Twig

```
{{ form_widget(form.publisher, {'attr': {'class': class, 'data-toggle': 'tagsinput', 'data-publishers': form.publisher.vars.publishers|json_encode } }) }}
{{ form_widget(form.publisher, {'attr': {'class': class, 'data-toggle': 'tagsinput', 'data-authors': form.publisher.vars.authors|json_encode } }) }}
```

This is the code I use for Editors and Authors, so that **you can compare the one that works and the one that doesn't work**. They are not so different, but something is wrong, and I don't know what it is or what I need to change.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found a solution. I have made all the changes in both Transformers, because the problem was the format to which I converted the entity and vice versa.